# Variable content to use as .grid_forget()

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to use forget() on the last active tkinter frame. 
My idea is to use a for statement to check all avaiable frames which get saved in a list like:

```
frameList = ["probabilityFrame","itemFrame","welcomeFrame","newsFrame"]
```

I want to use grid_forget() on the last active frame when switching to a new one.

Instead of doing something like my current solution which works but isnt good practise:

```
root = Tk()
root.title('title')
welcomeFrame = Frame(root)
itemFrame = Frame(root)
...

if(lastFrame == "probabilityFrame"):
    probabilityFrame.grid_forget()
elif(lastFrame =="itemFrame"):
    itemFrame.grid_forget()
elif(lastFrame =="welcomeFrame"):
    welcomeFrame.grid_forget()
elif(lastFrame =="newsFrame"):
    newsFrame.grid_forget()
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
for elemenst in frameList:
    if(lastFrame == element):

        >>>elements<<<.grid_forget()
        ex probabilityFrame.grid_forget()
```

But this isnt working because elements isnt the right object even tho it contains "probabilityFrame"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to store the frames rather than strings.

```
frameList = []

a_frame = tk.Frame(...)
frameList.append(a_frame)
...
another_frame = tk.Frame(...)
frameList.append(another_frame)
...
frameList[-1].grid_forget()
```